# How can you reduce the strength of an electromagnet gradually along its length?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

I am trying an experiment which involves accelerating a ball using electromagnets. My question is how can you reduce the strength of a electromagnet along its length gradually?

So to give a bit more context, the ball is parallel to the electromagnet. Imagine the line is the magnet and the ball is the period: |. What this means is that the force needs to be applied in the horizontal direction or perpendicular to the direction the electromagnet extends in. Now imagine this electromagnet is about maybe 1 meter long. The top of this magnet has a strength of maybe 1 newton while the bottom has a strength of 0  newtons. So from top to bottom the electromagnet needs to gradually go from 1 to 0 newtons in strength horizontally. That means half way down it is 0.5, and a fourth way down it is 0.75. But let me stress gradually because that also means that a hundredth the way down it is 0.99. However if it is not possible for it to be gradual to the millionth, it is okay. At least to the hundredth, and if even that is not possible, just tell me what you have in mind however not gradual it is. If multiple electromagnets are needed to accomplish this, that is okay too. As long as it is not an large amount. Also if this effect cannot be accomplished with just a long electromagnet, but rather a different method entirely(which still requires electromagnets), that is okay as well. As long as it has the same effect of a gradually decreasing strength in the direction of the ball.

Finally, if you have any questions about the question, feel free to ask. I will try to answer them as quickly as possible. However don't just vote to close the question, just tell me what you need clarification on, and I will fix it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

turns per meter. Reduce it. A turn is one wrap of the wire.

on 2nd thought No.
ON 3rd thought, maybe.

Since $\nabla\cdot\vec B=0$, you have to count on "B" leaking out of the side to make that work. so for a given internal diameter, there is probably a limit to how fast your decrease B on the axis, per unit length.